# wp_mail sends email twice inside function updated_postmeta

Tags: wp-mail, post-meta

I made a custom function so when postmeta updated to a specific value I send custom email use `wp_mail()`.

Email sends successfully, but it creates two at the same time.

Here my code:

```
function email_notification_by_status()
{

// Global Variable

$post_id = get_The_ID();
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
$dd_status = get_post_meta($post_id, 'screening_status', true);
$dd_analyst = get_post_meta($post_id, 'select_analyst', true);

//Completed

if ('Completed' == $dd_status)
    {

    $args = array(
        'role' => 'client',
        'blog_id' => $blog_id
    );
    $client_infos = get_users($args);
    foreach($client_infos as $client_info)
        {
        $client_email = $client_info->user_email;
        $to = $client_email;
        $subject = 'Due diligence is Complete';
        $body = 'Lorem ipsum';
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
        }
    }
}

add_filter('updated_postmeta', 'email_notification_by_status');
```

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you receiving 2 emails because of the foreach loop? You are currently sending mails to all users..

Comment: I think `updated_postmeta` is a action. So you should hook it using `add_action` not `add_filter`. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_postmeta/

Answer (score -1):

Remove `foreach` and directly add this code:

```
$client_infos = get_users($args);
if($client_infos)
{
    $client_email = $client_info[0]->user_email;
    $to = $client_email;
    $subject = 'Due diligence is Complete';
    $body = 'Lorem ipsum';
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

Comment: It's not a very good idea. Your code will cause problems, if there is no user found...

Comment: it's code perfect working if user found and no any kind of problem in it if user not found

Comment: well, yes. After you’ve edited it ;)